# Update a d3 barcharts on a "bounds_changed" google map event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to generate and update barcharts on a "bounds_changed" google map event with d3.js.

In my XSL file I would like to display the chart in the balise bellow :

```
<svg class="chart"></svg>
```

The graph are generated once, but never update when I move the map.

Here is an excerpt of my script :
The barcharts code come from an example of d3 tutorials.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(carte, 'bounds_changed', function() {

    var df = [Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+10),Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+10),Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+10),Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+10),Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+10)];

    var width = 420,
        barHeight = 20;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(df)])
        .range([0, width]);

    var chart = d3.select(".chart")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", barHeight * df.length);

    var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
        .data(df)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("width", x)
        .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

    bar.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
        .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
```

Why my "charts" is now "blocked" and can't be updated ? Can't it be "selected" a second time this way ?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hard to see what's going on without a complete example. Did you verify that the handler function is executed?

Comment: `bar` is the selection resulting from `enter()`, which is why your view only updates the first time. There's nothing in your code addressing the non-entering selection upon subsequent `bounds_changed`.

Comment: The only thing that would change is the height and width of the SVG. Is it the case that this changes indeed as expected?

Comment: Oh ok, thank you I understand now how the enter selection works with the keys. This helped me a lot http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.fr/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html
So, I'm now looking for how to replace the existing element with the 0 key, with exit and remove.
Thanks again.

Comment: Fixed :)
I just added :

`d3.selectAll('g').data([]).order().exit().remove();`

Before my d3 code.

Comment: Would you mind posting that as an answer for future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ok, thank you I understand now how the enter selection works with the keys. 
This helped me a lot knowledgestockpile.blogspot.fr/2012/01/… 
So, I'm now looking for how to replace the existing element with the 0 key, with exit and remove. Thanks again.

Fixed :) I just added :

```
d3.selectAll('g').data([]).order().exit().remove();
```

EDIT :

The line above, work if the data is a javascript array. But I would like to draw the same thing with datas in a json doc.

for example :

```
data = [
  { "id": 1, "x": Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+10)},
  { "id": 2, "x": Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+10)},
  { "id": 3, "x": Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+10)}
]
```

I read that I should use the key function (function(d) { return d.x; }) to remove it with exit().remove(). 
I tried :

```
d3.selectAll('g').data(data, function(d) { return d.x; }).order().exit().remove();
```

But nothing happen and I can't see why. Or maybe because my "data" are never the sames, 
and then it's impossible to find the respective keys?
If someone see where my problem could be, thank you.